# How do I install wpa_supplicant on bare embedded (ARM) linux (3.0.8)?

Tags: wifi, linux-kernel, cross-compilation, wpa-supplicant

### Environment

- FriendlyARM mini210s
- Linux 3.0.8 armv7l
- Cross-compilling

I need to install `wpa_supplicant`, how do I do that?

Shall I get the source for wpa_supplicant and place it somewhere in my Linux tree? Where?

## UPDATE 20141223

Following [these instructions](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM)

Installed Netlink Protocol Library Suite on my VM, now trying to cross-compile and install `iw`

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/iw/iw-3.17.tar.gz
tar -xzf iw-3.17.tar.gz
cd iw-3.17/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/pkgconfig
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

getting this error

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/iw-3.17$ make
 CC   info.o
info.c: In function 'print_phy_handler':
info.c:518: error: implicit declaration of function 'htole16'   <=== 
make: *** [info.o] Error 1
```

all I could find about it is [here](https://gnunet.org/bugs/view.php?id=1982)

not sure how to proceed further ...

## UPDATE 20141223 BIS

tried this

```
wget http://hostap.epitest.fi/releases/wpa_supplicant-2.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf wpa_supplicant-2.2.tar.gz
cd wpa_supplicant-2.2/wpa_supplicant
cp defconfig .config
make CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
make install DESTDIR=/home/export/rootfs
```

but still getting these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the compiler provided in FriendlyARM toolschain (download from friendlARM [ftp server](ftp://ftp.friendlyarm.net)):

export CC=/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

I followed these [instructions](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM)

Modified `.config` as follow:

```
CFLAGS += -I/home/vagrant/libnl-3.2.24/include
LIBS += -L/home/vagrant/libnl-3.2.24/lib

# Use libnl v2.0 (or 3.0) libraries.
CONFIG_LIBNL20=y

# Use libnl 3.2 libraries (if this is selected, CONFIG_LIBNL20 is ignored)
CONFIG_LIBNL32=y
```

Note that I had to compile `libnl-3.2.24` first.